# Teams meeting invitation and Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, microsoft-teams

When I receive an invitation to a Teams meeting the invitaion mail lacks the links to join/open the meeting. I have no clue why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Teams meeting join information is contained within the DESCRIPTION field of a vCalendar file sent by Outlook.

Apparently, [Thunderbird is unable to display content from embedded vCalendar content](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505024). One solution would to be installed an extension to display the vCalendar content. Some extensions that claim this functionality can be found on [Thunderbird's add-on directory](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/tag/vcalendar).

---

**Update**

I sent an invite created by Microsoft Teams version 1.3 to my email and the join meeting invitation was also included in the `text/plain` portion of the email. So it looks like the content is not only available in the vCalendar portion, but also should be included in the body of the email.